# How can I specify how long I want an overlay on a video to last with FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm making a video for YouTube, and I've already edited and touched it up in a full video editing program. The last thing I want to do is add an overlay banner with *subscribe* and *playlist* buttons which I'll turn into annotations. I want this to appear for the first 5 seconds of the video. Unfortunately my full video editing program can't due that, so I'd like to use FFMPEG to achieve this effect.

I've seen a few tutorials about this ([this one](http://www.idude.net/index.php/how-to-watermark-a-video-using-ffmpeg/) in particular seemed pretty good), but none of them mention how to specify the duration of the overlay.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could achieve this? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: One idea is to chain a `fade` filter to an `overlay`, but I haven't tried it so I don't know if it will work as expected.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I'm willing to try it. How exactly would I do this? :)

Comment: I'm not sure, and I am unable to try it myself now. Asking at the ffmpeg-user mailing list may provide an answer. Make sure you're using a recent ffmpeg build.

Answer (score 6):

### Fade and Overlay

You can chain a fade and overlay filter together like so:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f image2 -loop 1 -r 24 -i banner.png -filter_complex \
'[1:v]fade=out:96:24:alpha=1[wm];[0:v][wm]overlay=10:10[outv]' \
-map [outv] -map 0:a -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast output.mp4
```

`-f image2 -loop 1 -r 24 -i banner.png` turns banner.png into a 24fps video, looping to infinity.

`[1:v]fade=out:96:24:alpha=1[wm]` makes the watermark begin fading out at the 96th frame (4 seconds @ 24fps), and fade out over 24 frames (1 second @ 24fps); and it will fade out the *alpha channel*, meaning the watermark will turn transparent rather than fading to a black block. This creates an output labelled [wm]. Note that the lowest you can go for the length of the fade is 1 frame.

`[0:v][wm]overlay=0:0[outv]` [overlays](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1) the banner on input.mp4, creating an output labelled [outv].

`-map [outv] -map 0:a` tells ffmpeg to use [outv] and the audio from input.mp4 in the output. The rest of the options are encoding options.

You can make the banner fade in *and* out by chaining two fade filters. The following will make the banner fade in starting at frame 96, with a duration of 24 frames; and then fade out starting at frame 216 (9 seconds @ 24fps), for a duration of 24 frames:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f image2 -loop 1 -r 24 -i banner.png -filter_complex \
'[1:v]fade=in:96:24:alpha=1,fade=out:216:24:alpha=1[wm];[0:v][wm]overlay=10:10[outv]' \
-map [outv] -map 0:a -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast output.mp4
```

### Stream Seeking with `-ss` and `-t`

This achieves a similar end-result, but requires the creation of larger intermediate files. *However*, it only transcodes the first five-second section, and so will save on processing power and possibly be faster.

This involves cutting the video into two bits using `-t` and `-ss`, putting the watermark over the first, five-second video, and then [concatenating](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) the two videos together.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png \
-filter_complex '[0:v][1:v]overlay[outv]' -map [outv] -map 0:a \
-t 5 -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset veryfast start.mp4

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 5 -c copy end.mp4
```

Then concatenate the two videos using the concat demuxer: first create a file called inputs.txt, containing the following lines:

```
file 'start.mp4'
file 'end.mp4'
```

Then,

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i inputs.txt -c copy output.mp4
```